# How to throw a XmlSchemaException on XML Schema validation errors?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, schema

Calling `Validate()` on an **XmlDocument** requires passing in a `ValidationEventHandler` delegate.  That event function gets a `ValidationEventArgs` parameter which in turn has an `Exception` property of the type `XmlSchemaException`.  Whew!

My current code looks like this:

```
ValidationEventHandler onValidationError = delegate(object sender,
    ValidationEventArgs args)
{
    throw(args.Exception);
}

doc.Validate(onValidationError);
```

Is there some other method I'm overlooking which simply *throws* the `XmlSchemaException` if validation fails (warnings ignored entirely)?

Comment: On my system (.NET Framework 4.5.2 / 4.7.2) I don't get the orignal XmlSchemaException. I just get a sparse copy without SourceSchemaObject etc. variables.

Comment: Aah, I was not exactly right. Sometimes you get original XmlSchemaException in (ValidationEventArgs)args.Exception.InnerException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Validate method takes the ValidationEventHandler delegate, it is left up to the developer to decide what to do with the excpetion. What you are doing is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Passing `null` for the `validationEventHandler` parameter will throw an exception if there are any errors.

The MSDN documentation for the [Extensions.Validate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.extensions.validate?#System_Xml_Schema_Extensions_Validate_System_Xml_Linq_XDocument_System_Xml_Schema_XmlSchemaSet_System_Xml_Schema_ValidationEventHandler_) method describes the `validationEventHandler` parameter as:

> A `ValidationEventHandler` for an event that occurs when the reader
>   encounters validation errors. If `null`, throws an exception upon
>   validation errors.